# Is there any formal calculation method for partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am learning undergraduate level PDE. The massive calculation of partial derivatives often confuse me a lot. Though I can understand them after some careful check, I am curious about how mathematician find these 'strange' derivative deformation? Is there any **formal** calculation method for doing these partial derivatives? For example$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})-\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\\=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^{2}$$

Comment: Depends a lot on what you're trying to do, and sometimes on the modeling context.

Comment: I'm told that Tensor analysis simplifies this so that it's intuitive.  I've never studied it though.  You've could check out these videos:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlXfTHzgMRULkodlIEqfgTS-H1AY_bNtq

Comment: The equalities you have there are derived by just using the product rule (it's easier to see if you go right-to-left). Many such formulae are just applications of the chain rule and product rule, some times disguised by moving terms to the other side of the $=$. Is that the kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: I know these equalities only make use of chain rule and product rule . I mean can we view partial derivative as something like 'opeartor' with some formal operations? So that I can calculate these like algebric manipulation untill find the correct form that I need for specific problem?@lan@Arthur

Comment: Thank you @NicNic8, you got my point. I will watch these videos. Really Thanks!